# django-haystack urlpatterns include('haystack.urls') where does it lead to?

Tags: django, django-haystack, url-pattern

I've recently begun to learn/install django/haystack/solr.

Following the tutorial given in haystack site,

```
I have urlpatterns = pattern('', r'^search/', include('haystack.urls'))
```

I found haystack installed in /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/haystack
and located urls.py there.

It has

```
urlpatterns=patterns('haystack.views', url(r'^$', SearchView(), name='haystack_search'),)
```

I thought the second argument of url() should be callable object.
I looked at the views.py and SearchView is a class.
What is going on here?
What's get called eventually?

Comment: It is the `__call__` method of `SearchView`. as sberry's answer said.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Doesn't exactly answer your question, but a class can be a callable:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     def __call__(self):
...             print "Called me"
... 
>>> 
>>> foo = Foo()
>>> foo()
Called me
```